# Converting csv for fixtures

Tags: django

I am unable to convert test data in **CSV** format using `csv2json.py` so that I can use the same in fixtures which should have the format pk, model, and then the fields.

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "wkw2.Lawyer", 
        "fields": {
            "school": "The George Washington University Law School", 
            "last": "Babbas", 
            "firm_url": "http://www.graychase.com/babbas", 
            "year_graduated": "2005", 
            "firm_name": "Gray & Chase", 
            "first": "Amr A"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: So you want to convert this to a JSON ? And for that you're using some script ? Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes I need the data in the above format which is expected by fixtures so that I can use them to unit test the code

Comment: What are the fixtures? Because we need to fix those fixtures and for that we need to see the code/ fixture

Comment: Am getting the following error on running the script csv2json.                            "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: Paste the code of csv2json.py here please

Comment: From this link is what I used https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1680/

Comment: @mishsx Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from one time that helped me convert CSV to JSON. Let me know if you need something else:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","IDNumber","Message")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```